# "[ERROR] Could not parse package.json. Is it a valid .JSON file?"

Tags: json, ionic-framework, ionic3

I pulled a GIT project in bitbucket and encountered this error when I tried to "ionic serve" the project. In the owner's project, there was no error detected.

[image]

Comment: Could you post the json file? Or you could copy the contents to: http://json.parser.online.fr

Comment: Can you show your `package.json` file?

Comment: where can I find that package.json in my project? Sorry, I'm really new to this.

Comment: You can find `package.json` in the main folder of your project

Comment: did you run this command in your project folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you probably have some format issue on your `package.json`. To know where this comes from, simply **copy the content** of your `package.json` using your code editor or your CLI (`$ cat package.json | pbcopy`) and **paste it** into [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/). It will show you which part is badly formatted.

Comment: Thanks for the mentioning nice tool +1 :)

Comment: Nice tool... except I pasted my package.json with the same error message into the tool and it says it's valid.
Back to Square One. :(